# Hide Default Message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, filter

I'm fetching data and showing under a search input

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try{
      const response = await axios("/posts");
      setAPIData(response.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
      
      } catch(error) {
        setError(true);
        console.error(error);
      }
      
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  console.log(APIData)
```

The user types in the search input and it show the results and if there is no results it shows a message "No Results Found!" .. the problem is this message is showing by default which is a bad UI, I only want this message to show if there is no result and by default shows the APIData

```
        {filteredResults && filteredResults.length > 0 ? (
          

            filteredResults.map((post) => {

                return (
                    <div className="card" key={post._id}>
                    <div className="card-content">
                    <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="link">
                    <h2 className="results-title">
                        {post.title}
                    </h2>
                    <ol className="card-username">
                        {post.username}      
                    </ol>
                    </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
            })
            
        ) : (
          <h1>No results found!</h1>
        )}
```

I didn't if I should another useState for it or there another way !

Comment: @user16320675 sorry for that I just saw it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isLoading` state for conditional rendering:

```
{isLoading ? (
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
) : (
    <>
        {filteredResults && filteredResults.length > 0 ? (
            filteredResults.map((post) => {
                return (
                    <div className="card" key={post._id}>
                        <div className="card-content">
                            <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="link">
                                <h2 className="results-title">{post.title}</h2>
                                <ol className="card-username">{post.username}</ol>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })
        ) : (
            <h1>No results found!</h1>
        )}
    </>
)}
```

Remember to set `isLoaidng` state to false if the request fails:

```
try {
   // ...    
} catch(error) {
  // ...
} finally {
   setIsLoading(false); // <==
}
```